# Camel TypeConverters and Object inheritance

Tags: java, apache-camel

I currently have a situation with an object that has 2 sub classes and I would like to have a typeConverter use the parent class and manage the logic for each subclass separately is this possible?

```
class MyParent {}
class SubClass1 extends MyParent {}
class SubClass2 extends MyParent {}
```

I currently receive a list  which I use a split() on and I wanted a type converter to manage the subclasses

```
from("direct:source")
    .split(body()).streaming()
        .beanRef(MyBean.class, "myMethod");


class MyBean {
    public void myMethod(MyParent parent) {
        //TODO stuff
    }
}
```

When I try to do this, camel throws exceptions saying typeConverter not found for SubClass1 and SubClass2.  How can I properly manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write 2 type converters for SubClass1 and SubClass2, and then call some common code for the shared part.

Or you can use a fallback type converter.

You can find more details in the Camel documentation: http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html